Classical Yang-Mills Versus Quantum Yang-Mills
What insights do the study of instantons and minimizers of the Yang-Mills classical functional give for physics?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Do you understand how classical electromagnetism differs from quantized electromagnetism? Its $A_\mu$, the equivalent of an $A_\mu^a$ in Yang-Mills (but with only one possible value of $a$), gains a hat. Yang-Mills is the same: each $A_\mu^a$ is promoted to $\widehat{A}_\mu^a$, while $T^a$ is an unaffected constant generator.

I am not fully following the question and I would recommend a couple of useful texts that might at least help get some insight.  The first is a fairly well done discussion of Yang Mills theory which includes a good section on canonical quantization.  It is insightful in that it discusses the need for use of finite hilbert spaces to describe quantizing internal degrees of freedom like the color charge.
The other is a paper which takes a truly classical approach to Yang Mills theory by using point charges defined in a color space.  This imagines a treatment which is called color electrodynamics.
From their different treatments of the color charge in each of the papers I think it might help better show the contrast between the quantum and classical approaches one would take.
